# IE Parsing XML JQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

```
$.ajax({ 
        url : SrvHandlerCalendar, 
        type : 'post', 
        data : {"persona": str, "day2" : dia + '.' + mes + '.' + anio}, 
        timeout : 2000, 
        tryCount : 0, 
        retryLimit : 3, 
        cache: false,
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            var xml;
              if (typeof data == 'string') {
                xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xml.async = false;
                xml.loadXML(data);
              } else {
                xml = data;
              }





                $(xml).find('evento').each(function(){
                ai++;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var rdia = $(this).find('dia').text();
                var rmes = $(this).find('mes').text();
                var ranio = $(this).find('anio').text();
                var hora = $(this).find('hora').text();
                var horario = $(this).find('horario').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('d').text();
                var estado = $(this).find('estado').text();
                var localidad = $(this).find('localidad').text();
                var colonia = $(this).find('colonia').text();
                var calle = $(this).find('calle').text();
                var numero =  $(this).find('ncasa').text();
                var telefono = $(this).find('telefono').text();
                var celular =  $(this).find('celular').text();
                var persona =  $(this).find('persona').text();
                var creador =  $(this).find('creador').text();
                var observaciones =  $(this).find('observaciones').text();
                if(persona != $("#personas_select option:selected").text()) return 1;

                var html = "<font size=5>Informacion del evento con <u>" + persona + "</u></font><br>";
                html += "<font size=2>"+desc+"</font><br><br><br>";
                html += "<table class=\"datatable\"  cellpadding=10>"
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Hora de la Cita</strong></td><td>" + hora + horario+"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Domicilio</strong></td><td>" + calle + " #"+numero+"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Colonia</strong></td><td>" +colonia+"</td></tr>";
                //html += "<tr colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align: center;\"><td>Datos de contacto</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Telefono</strong></td><td>" + telefono +"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Celular</strong></td><td>" + celular +"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Encuestador</strong></td><td>" + creador +"</td></tr>" 
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Observaciones</strong></td><td>" + observaciones +"</td></tr></table>";

                 $('#datos').html(html); 

                /*

                var html = "<font size=5>Informacion del evento con <u>" + persona + "</u></font><br>";
                html += "<font size=2>"+desc+"</font><br>";
                html += "<table>"
                html += " <tr>  <td>Hora de la Cita</td><td>horario  y fecha</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr> <td>Domicilio</td><td>vdomicilio</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>Colonia</td><td>vcolonia</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>Datos de contacto</td><td>(no hay otra columna)</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>telefono</td><td></td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>celular</td><td></td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>encuestador</td><td></td></tr></table>";
                */




            });


            if($("#datos").html() == loading){
                $('#datos').html("Uups! No hay datos de evento para esta persona. <strong>Notificar de inmediato al administrador del sistema</strong> <a href=\"#\" onclick='alert(\"No se encontro el primer atributo XML\" + \" "+" \" )'> Ficha Técnica</a>"); 
            }


        }, 
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) { 
        if (textStatus == 'timeout') { 
             $('#datos').html(loading);
            this.tryCount++; 
            if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) { 
                //try again 
                $.ajax(this); 
                return; 
            } 
                $('#datos').html("Uups! Hubo un error procesando su solicitud <a href=\"#\" onclick='alert(\"Respuesta HTTP: \" + \" "+ xhr.status+" \" + \"\\nManejador del servidor: \" + \" " + SrvHandlerCalendar + " \"  + \"\\nDescripcion de error: \" + \" " + textStatus + " \"  + \"\\nIntentos: \" + \" " + this.retryLimit + " \" )'> Ficha Técnica</a>"); 
                return; 
        } 
        if (xhr.status == 500) { 
            $('#datos').html('Uups! Hubo un error con el servidor. Intente nuevamente mas tarde y pongase en contacto con el administrador de sistemas.'); 
        } else { 
            $('#datos').html("Uups! Hubo un error procesando su solicitud <a href=\"#\" onclick='alert(\"Respuesta HTTP: \" + \" "+ xhr.status+" \" + \"\\nManejador del servidor: \" + \" " + SrvHandlerCalendar + " \"  + \"\\nDescripcion de error: \" + \" " + textStatus + " \" )'> Ficha Técnica</a>"); 
        } 
    } 
    });`
```

And basically this:

```
    var xml;
              if (typeof data == 'string') {
                xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xml.async = false;
                xml.loadXML(data);
              } else {
                xml = data;
              }





                $(xml).find('evento').each(function(){
                ai++;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var rdia = $(this).find('dia').text();
                var rmes = $(this).find('mes').text();
                var ranio = $(this).find('anio').text();
                var hora = $(this).find('hora').text();
                var horario = $(this).find('horario').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('d').text();
                var estado = $(this).find('estado').text();
                var localidad = $(this).find('localidad').text();
                var colonia = $(this).find('colonia').text();
                var calle = $(this).find('calle').text();
                var numero =  $(this).find('ncasa').text();
                var telefono = $(this).find('telefono').text();
                var celular =  $(this).find('celular').text();
                var persona =  $(this).find('persona').text();
                var creador =  $(this).find('creador').text();
                var observaciones =  $(this).find('observaciones').text();
                if(persona != $("#personas_select option:selected").text()) return 1;

                var html = "<font size=5>Informacion del evento con <u>" + persona + "</u></font><br>";
                html += "<font size=2>"+desc+"</font><br><br><br>";
                html += "<table class=\"datatable\"  cellpadding=10>"
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Hora de la Cita</strong></td><td>" + hora + horario+"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Domicilio</strong></td><td>" + calle + " #"+numero+"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Colonia</strong></td><td>" +colonia+"</td></tr>";
                //html += "<tr colspan=\"2\" style=\"text-align: center;\"><td>Datos de contacto</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Telefono</strong></td><td>" + telefono +"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Celular</strong></td><td>" + celular +"</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Encuestador</strong></td><td>" + creador +"</td></tr>" 
                html += "<tr><td><strong>Observaciones</strong></td><td>" + observaciones +"</td></tr></table>";

                 $('#datos').html(html); 

                /*

                var html = "<font size=5>Informacion del evento con <u>" + persona + "</u></font><br>";
                html += "<font size=2>"+desc+"</font><br>";
                html += "<table>"
                html += " <tr>  <td>Hora de la Cita</td><td>horario  y fecha</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr> <td>Domicilio</td><td>vdomicilio</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>Colonia</td><td>vcolonia</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>Datos de contacto</td><td>(no hay otra columna)</td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>telefono</td><td></td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>celular</td><td></td></tr>";
                html += "<tr><td>encuestador</td><td></td></tr></table>";
                */




            });


            if($("#datos").html() == loading){
                $('#datos').html("Uups! No hay datos de evento para esta persona. <strong>Notificar de inmediato al administrador del sistema</strong> <a href=\"#\" onclick='alert(\"No se encontro el primer atributo XML\" + \" "+" \" )'> Ficha Técnica</a>"); 
            }
```

Only works on Chrome/Firefox and Not on IE.

I don't know why, I googled about JQuery and IE errors, tried the 'fixes' and they still do not work.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

It now works.
The problem with IE is that the XML It was receiving was bad because IE doesn't allow áéíóú letters (commonly used in spanish) instead displaying a square character therfor it could't process the XML.

Comment: What about just doing `dataType: "xml"` and not including the ActiveX stuff? XML parsing should work fine on IE.

Comment: Is this a problem with all ie versions or a specific version?

Comment: @pimvdb No, wont work. At least it doesn't on IE 8. If I remove all that, JQuery calls the error callback with textstatus parse error.

Comment: @use863021: Perhaps you might want to add a header `Content-Type: text/xml` on the server side: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/xml-parsing-in-ie-8.

Comment: @primvdb My first thinking was that perhaps that was the error but my PHP code (SrvHandlerCalendar -> "ajax-calendar.php") first line is header("Content-Type: text/xml");